# How can an ISO file be written (copied) to a disc as a single file using wodim?

Tags: iso, data-cd, wodim

**Problem**

An ISO file needs to be 'burned' to a disc as a file, not an ISO image, and by using wodim.

**Question**

How can an ISO file be written (copied) to a disc as a single file using wodim?

Comment: Do you mean, creating a disc with a filesystem on it, in which the ISO image is a file?

Comment: You mean you *don't* want to burn the iso image properly so that it is bootable, but just as a normal file?

Comment: @psusi: Yes, that is correct. I do not want to burn the image, just copy the ISO file over as an ISO file.

Comment: Then you need to use `genisoimage` to create an iso image that only contains the iso file, and burn *that* with wodim... or just use a gui and drag and drop the file to the drive and burn it, which does just that.

Comment: @psusi: The ISO has already been generated but as the question is asking, _**how** can an ISO file be copied as a file to a cd/dvd using wodim?_ (And no GUI available here, only shell).

Comment: @FrugalRasin, yes. and you do that by generating *another* iso image that only contains the first iso image.

Answer (score 1):

You can embed iso image into another iso image with `mkisofs`:

```
mkisofs -JR -o out.iso your.iso
```

Or just create a filesystem, for example ext2:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/path/to/image.ext2 bs=1M count=650
mke2fs -m0 /path/to/image.ext2
```

, mount it as a loop device and store your iso inside it:

```
mount -o loop /path/to/image.ext2 /mnt
cp /your/cd.iso /mnt
umount /mnt
```

Then burn resulting image.ext2 as usual with `wodim`.

If you need dvd size image, then change 650 to whatever dvd size will be acceptabe.

Comment: Yes, but that is not what the question is asking. What you have replied with is already obvious and using that command would create a CD/DVD of the ISO image file. The question is not to create a CD/DVD using the ISO image, but simply to write the file to the disc as a file, and to do so using wodim.

Comment: If you want to put in _into_ other ISO image, then probably `mkisofs` is your tool of choice. Alternatively you can put it into any other filesystem image precreated, then write it to disc with same commands. Sorry for any misundrerstandings that were taken place.

Comment: Yes, that might be a way to do it. I will try it out then comment again so you can update/edit your answer. Here is what I will be doing: creating an ISO of the ISO, then burning the newly created 'outer' ISO using wodim.

Comment: It worked. So the answer is: Wrap the ISO in another ISO using an image creation tool (for example genisoimage), then write the new 'outer' ISO with wodim.

Comment: OK, so it's just my little misreading. Now it should be a proper answer!

Comment: Prior to accepting your answer as correct, clarify your answer further by detailing the command(s) used to create an ext2/4 loop device, and how exactly to write that loop device to a disc.

Comment: @FrugalRasin, you generally don't want to write an ext4 filesystem to a cdrom.  While linux has no problem with any fs on a cdrom, most other operating systems will only recognize iso9660 or udf on cdroms.